# Identifying self-crossing/intersecting polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, select, self-intersection

I need to identify these polygons that are self-crossing.

[image]

I tried to run SAGA's "Polygon self-intersect" tool but it didn't work.

update: I tried to use check validity and other similar algorithms but all the results are similar to the picture below, the algorithms classified this messy polygon as valid.
[image]

Here is the link to the part of the shapefile containing this ugly guy: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x4sbV0jROgnghLnXJiN9kK_zI94Go_AC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are one polygon intersecting itself? Or is it intersecting another polygon in the same layer?

Comment: This is intersecting itself

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the ["Check validity"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#check-validity) tool from the `Vector geometry`.

It returns valid and invalid geometries as separate layers, and invalid output layer contains the reason of invalidity.

[image]

Comment: Yeah tried that but it is considered as valid.

Answer (score 10):

Using the following script, you can select features with self-crossing geometry. (after selecting layer)

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = layer.getFeatures()
selection = [f.id() for f in feats if any(['intersect' in e.what() for e in f.geometry().validateGeometry()])]
layer.select(selection)
```

[image]

Comment: that didn't work, same result as the native algorithm

Comment: Please share your data to get convenient help.

Comment: Ok, just did tks!

Answer (score 8):

Another solution is to use this expression within the ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) tool:

```py
not is_valid($geometry)
```

[image: result]

The same expression can be used within the ["Extract by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-expression) tool.

The [`is_valid()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#is-valid) function:

> Returns true if a geometry is valid; if it is well-formed in 2D
> according to the OGC rules.

Comment: none of them worked as well, I will update the question with my attempts

Answer (score 6):

I assume you have "one polygon intersecting another one" in your layer, and not "one polygon intersecting itself".

You can use a virtual layer and join the layer to itself where it intersects:

```sql
select row_number() over() as rnum, --To create a unique id column
       st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geom
from overlap a
join --join the layer to itself
overlap b
on st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry) 
where a.id<b.id and st_dimension(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry))=2
--Where the polygons are not the same and the result of their intersection is a polygon (2 dimensions, or you would also get points and lines)
```

[image]

You can then right-click the layer and export to file.

Comment: Well it is one feature only that one, I also have other polygons intersecting other features in the same layer but that's  not the issue here. And I tried to run this code you told me without success of creating the virtual layer, never used this approach before, maybe I am doing it wrong but I don't think this will help in this case. I will provide the shapefile in my updated question so anyone can try.